# What is the different between NSArray Parsing?

Tags: objective-c, ios

What is the difference between of Parsing in the following code segments.
which codes segments is faster in Parsing?

```
NSArray *arr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Apple",@"Macbook", nil];

NSMutableArray *data = (NSMutableArray *)arr;
```

(and)

```
NSArray *arr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Apple",@"Macbook", nil];

NSMutableArray *data = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:arr];
```

Comment: You're not actually "parsing" anything here. Your second example is closer to being correct, but you leak an empty mutable array.

Comment: ...all answers given are correct and to the point. I would still like to add something. Maybe it is just your wording but I am really irritated by your question for speed ("faster in parsing"). If you really need to optimize, use Instruments for measuring and do only optimize things that turn out to be a bottleneck. Measuring is much better than assuming.

Answer (score 3):

You have the same mistake in both snippets, you allocate memory for the object, and then assign something else to data, which makes you lose the previous (and have memory leak), e.g. this:

```
NSMutableArray *data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
data = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:arr];
```

should be

```
NSMutableArray *data = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:arr];
```

Now for the question itself:

1. The first case is a bad idea, you cast the NSArray, but you canot modify it, as you didn't really changed its type, only assigned it to NSMutaleArray pointer.
2. The second case will create a new NSMutableArray which is mutable, with the contents of the NSArray, and this is cool, you may alter this array now.

Comment: +1 that and in that first snippet he assigns a non mutable NSArray to a mutable NSMutableArray which will trigger an exception if he later tries to mutate it.

Comment: @Till - you are right, first I was too much into the comment and commited the answer before I completed it. edited.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you want is either:

```
NSArray *arr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Apple",@"Macbook", nil];
NSMutableArray *data = [arr mutableCopy];
```

or:

```
NSMutableArray *data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Apple",@"Macbook", nil];
```